# Custom post type URl Cutomization

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am creating a custom CPT where I have customized CPT URL structure of CPT, I am using the rewrite rule for this but it is conflicting
This is a Lessons CPT, I want to remove lessons from the URL and if any category or subcategory is selected in the post then the URL structure should be parent category/child-category/post name, I have also customized the category URL structure where I  want to remove lesson-category in this example:-
`http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson-category/california/` the URL should be like this  `http://localhost/custom_theme/california/`

I have Custom Lessons CPT where I want to customize the URl structure Here is the scenario:-

I  want to remove the lesson in Custom CPT - `http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson/paino_lesson/` the URL should be like this  `http://localhost/custom_theme/paino_lesson/`

if any category or subcategory is selected in the post then the URL structure should be parent category/child category/post name,

I  want to remove the lesson category in this example:- `http://localhost/custom_theme/lesson-category/california/` the URL should be like this  `http://localhost/custom_theme/california/`

// START: CPT 'Lessons'

```
add_action('init', 'register_lessons_post_type');
function register_lessons_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Lesson',
        'singular_name'         => 'Lesson',
        'menu_name'             => 'Lesson',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New Lesson',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Lesson',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Lesson',
        'new_item'              => 'New Lesson',
        'view_item'             => 'View Lesson',
        'view_items'            => 'View Lessons',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Lessons',
        'not_found'             => 'No lesson found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No lesson found in trash',
        'all_items'             => 'All Lessons',
        'archives'              => 'Lessons',
        'attributes'            => 'Template',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into lesson',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this lesson',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter lessons list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Lesson list navigation',
        'items_list'            => 'Lessons list',
        'item_published'        => 'Lesson published',
        'item_published_privately' => 'Lesson published privately',
        'item_reverted_to_draft'    => 'Lesson reverted to draft',
        'item_scheduled'            => 'Lesson scheduled',
        'item_updated'              => 'Lesson updated',
        'taxonomies'               => array( 'lesson_category' ), // Link to the custom taxonomy
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => '/%lesson_category%'), // Set the custom permalink structure
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'elementor'),
    );

    register_post_type('lessons', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'register_lesson_category_taxonomy');
function register_lesson_category_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'City',
        'singular_name' => 'City',
        'search_items' => 'Search City',
        'all_items' => 'All Cities',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent City or State',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent City or State:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit City',
        'update_item' => 'Update City',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New City',
        'new_item_name' => 'New City Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Cities or Locations',
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => '/', // Set the slug for the 'lesson_category' taxonomy
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    );

    // Link this taxonomy to the 'lessons' custom post type
    register_taxonomy('lesson_category', array('lessons'), $args);
}

// Change the permalink structure for the lessons post type
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_lessons_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function custom_lessons_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ('lessons' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status) {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'lesson_category');

        if (!empty($terms)) {
            $term_slugs = array();

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                // Traverse through parent categories and add them to the array
                $parent_chain = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'lesson_category');
                $parent_chain = array_reverse($parent_chain);
                foreach ($parent_chain as $parent_id) {
                    $parent_term = get_term($parent_id, 'lesson_category');
                    $term_slugs[] = $parent_term->slug;
                }

                $term_slugs[] = $term->slug;
            }

            $post_link = home_url('/') . implode('/', $term_slugs) . '/' . $post->post_name . '/';
        } else {
            // No category selected, keep the URL simple
            $post_link = home_url('/') . $post->post_name . '/';

            
        }
    }

    return $post_link;
}

// Add the %lesson_category% tag to the rewrite rules
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_lessons_rewrite_rules');
function custom_lessons_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();

    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'lesson_category', 'hide_empty' => false));

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_path = $term->slug;
        $new_rules[$term_path . '/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lesson_category=$matches[1]';
    }

    // Add a rule for the case when no category is selected
    $new_rules['([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?lessons=$matches[1]';

    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```